# Install Grub in Windows manually?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7

'm shayne. 
I am using windows 7. And also I used Ubuntu 12.4. But I had to reinstall Windows 7 and now the grub has gone. Can I install grub here logging in windows? If so how could I do it?

Comment: try boot-repair to reinstall the grub.